# Android Google Maps moveCamera not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the following `method` to move the camera:

```
private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, GoogleMap map) {
    Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude);
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
}
```

When I am using it inside `OnMapReady` like this:

```
private void initMapHome() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.harta_adauga_adresa_acasa);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is readyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
            gmap = googleMap;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            gmap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            gmap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            gmap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            gmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            gmap.setOnMapClickListener(latLng -> {
                 gmap.clear();
                 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                     .position(latLng)
                     .title(adresa);
                 gmap.addMarker(options).showInfoWindow();
            });
         moveCamera(pozitie_curenta, DEFAULT_ZOOM, gmap);
       }
   });
}
```

The camera animates in a nice manner to the selected `position`, the `pozitie_curenta` `LatLng` created somewhere else in my code. Now, I have a `AutoCompleteTextView` that returns the `places` (I am using the  one created by Mukesh Solanki from `github`), and I am looking to move the camera on the `selected place` from the `AutoCompleteTextView`. I have the following code:

```
adresa_home.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Place place = (Place) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            adresa_home.setText(place.getDescription());
            placesApi.fetchPlaceDetails(place.getId(), new OnPlacesDetailsListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPlaceDetailsFetched(PlaceDetails placeDetails) {
                            latitudine_acasa = placeDetails.getLat();
                            longitudine_acasa = placeDetails.getLng();
                            updateHartaHome(latitudine_acasa, longitudine_acasa, place.getDescription());
                        }

                @Override
                        public void onError(String s) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
            );
        }
    });
```

The `place` is fetched correctly, and I get the `latitude` and `longitude` correctly. The `method` `updateHartaHome` is looking like this:

```
private void updateHartaHome(double lat, double lng, String title) {
    acasa = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(pozitie_curenta)
            .title(title);
    gmap.addMarker(options).showInfoWindow();
    moveCamera(acasa, DEFAULT_ZOOM, null, gmap);
}
```

Debugging the code I've come to the conclusion that the problem it's with the `moveCamera` from the `updateHartaHome` which is never called. Setting a `breakpoint` on the line `gmap.addMarker(options).showInfoWindow();` gets me the following:
[image]

So, eveything looks fine, but the `map` doesn't update and, it also doesn't add the `marker`. Setting the `breakpoint` on the `moveCamera` line, it never gets accesed. Any help would be appreciated, I've been going mad over this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this once inside your `onMapReady` method

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(placeLatitude, placeLongitude))
                    .zoom(16)
                    .bearing(0)
                    .tilt(45)
                    .build();
mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

where `mGoogleMap` is defined as

```
 mGoogleMap = googleMap;
 mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
```

if you want to add Marker do this before moving the camera

```
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(placeLatitude, placeLongitude)));
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to click on the map and move the camera

```
 mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                mGoogleMap.clear();
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude)));

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude))
                    .zoom(16)
                    .bearing(0)
                    .tilt(45)
                    .build();
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have tried this, the camera still doesn't move. I have seen the edit later: `onMapReady` it works fine they way I am using it. The problem it's when I am trying to move it once more

Comment: make sure your latitude, longitude is of double data type?

Comment: yes, they are. As seen in the photo added in the question, the `LatLng` it's correctly created.

Comment: please check the updated answer use this function to move camera mGoogleMap.getUiSettings()

Comment: Please check the EDIT in answer and try clicking on the map other than the current location.

Comment: Like that it works. But I need to move the camera according the `latitude` and `longitude` fround from places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224090/discussion-between-kartik-agarwal-and-costin).